# Data card connection in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: modem

I am a new user of Ubuntu 16.04 and I have dual booted it along with Windows 7.

I have a huawei E303F Data card. But when I plug in the data card nothing is happening. I have opened the files in data card and I can't find any Linux files.

I have searched on Google for three days and tried whatever told in Ubuntu forums, you tube etc. but couldn't find any answer.

I don't know about coding even for opening a simple file directory. Can anyone please help me step by step to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [UbuntuForums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008275):

1. Download the zip from [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4oQlH9i38JPR3hDRlNXbFRWYjQ).
2. Extract the zip by right-clicking on it.
3. Then, open terminal and type

   cd ~/Downloads/ubuntu/linux_mbb_install
4. Then change the needed file to executable

   chmod +x install
5. Finally,

   sudo ./install

And folow the instructions accordingly.

Comment: Can I manually download it from a PC with Internet connection and put it in the download folders of my PC to do the above steps.

Comment: @ponnumani Yes, ofcourse

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didnt worked .I downloaded the zip file from my mobile and put it in the downloads and extracted the files there itself and ran the command in third step. But it shows no such file or directory.

Comment: @ponnumani - Do this and post the output - `cd ~/Downloads; ls -A`

Comment: .bash_history examples.desktop .profile                         .bash_logout .gconf public                                                  .bashrc .gnome2 .sudo_as_admin_successful                .cache .gnupg templates                                                   .config .ICEauthority ubuntu.zip                              Desktop .local videos                                                            .dmrc .Mozilla .Xauthority                                                  Documents Music .Xsession-errors.                                    Downloads pictures .Xsession-errors.old

Comment: thats not your downloads directory but your `$HOME` directory

Comment: Anyways as you can see there is your `ubuntu.zip` so extract your zip and then instead of step 3 do - `cd ~/ubuntu/linux_mbb_install` and continue

Comment: Oh.. thanks for your time. You know iam new to Ubuntu so basically I don't know much about it.anyway I'll try to install the files thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help I changed the 7zr file as executable and followed till 5th step it shows.successful and  press any key to exit.

Comment: @ponnumani - Guess! the installation was successful. Reboot and see if it works